# Creating a new variable that indicates a specific condition using two preexisting variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, dummy-variable

I have an individual-level dataset with demographic information of each person. It also provides a unique household id along with other variables:

```
id     if_adult (>18 yrs old)     marital_status
1          1                       Single
1          1                       Single
2          1                       Married
2          1                       Married
2          0                       Married
```

Each household has at least one adult who is single or two adults who are either married or single. Some households also have children. I am trying to create a dummy variable called "unmarried couple" that will correctly categorize a household that has exactly two single adults. Obviously, there are duplicate rows with the same household id so I want each to be labeled correctly. Currently, the code I have is:

```
individual_data$`unmarried couple` <- ifelse((individual_data$if_adult == 
"1" & individual_data$id == individual_data$id) & 
individual_data$marital_status == "Single", "1","0")
```

But this incorrectly categorizes the single-person led households (i.e. single moms and single dads with children) as being unmarried couples. This is key - if I can figure this out then it will be accurate. To rectify this issue, I am attempting to create a new variable that indicates the total number of adults per household:

```
id     if_adult (>18 yrs old)     marital_status   total_adults
1          1                       Single          2
1          1                       Single          2
2          1                       Married         2
2          1                       Married         2
2          0                       Married         2
```

Then create my desired variable by filtering out the single-led households and setting the condition as having at least two adults

```
individual_data$`unmarried couple` <- ifelse((individual_data$total_adults 
== 2 & individual_data$id == individual_data$id) & 
individual_data$marital_status == "Single", "1","0")
```

I ultimately want it to look like this and for the rest of the data:

```
id     if_adult     marital_status   total_adults  unmarried couple  
1          1           Single          2             1
1          1           Single          2             1
2          1           Married         2             0    
2          1           Married         2             0
2          0           Married         2             0
```

Comment: I should also add that I have not been successful in creating the total adults variable

Answer (score 1):

What about this using `dplyr` and `group_by` to make this a bit easier. It checks to make sure there are exactly two single adults for each id.

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(unmarried_couple = sum(if_adult*(marital_status=="Single"))==2,
    total_adults = sum(if_adult))
```

tested with

```
dd <- read.table(text="id     if_adult     marital_status
1          1                       Single
1          1                       Single
2          1                       Married
2          1                       Married
2          0                       Married", header=T)
```

Comment: I am either getting these two errors: Error: unexpected '=' in "unmarried_couple %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(unmarried_couple  ="    OR  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Did you get them when copy/pasting my code as written? Or when trying to change it for your real data?

Comment: I tried changing it to my real data. Could you give me some suggestions on how to create a variable with the total number of adults in each household, instead?

Comment: @manutd93 I updated my answer to also calculate "total_adults"

Answer (score 0):

===edits at the end===

If you want to stick to Base R then the following solution might work for you:

```
individual_data$unmarried_couples <- ifelse(individual_data$marital_status %in% c("Single", "1", "0"),
    individual_data$total_adults %/% 2,
    0)
```

I have used the expression `total_adults %/%  2` to calculate the number of unmarried couples living in a household since I thought it might be the case that a household has more than 2 single adults living in it.

Tested on:

```
id     if_adult (>18 yrs old)     marital_status   total_adults
1          1                       Single          2
1          1                       Single          2
2          1                       Married         2
2          1                       Married         2
2          0                       Married         2
```

===edits==
Since you are struggling with the variable `adults_in_household` here is a completely reproducible code:

```
individual_data <-  data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  if_adult = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0),
  marital_status = c("Single", "Single", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Single", "Single")
)

library(dplyr)

individual_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(adults_in_household = sum(if_adult))
```

The output of this code should be:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id if_adult marital_status adults_in_household
  <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>                        <dbl>
1     1        1 Single                           2
2     1        1 Single                           2
3     2        1 Married                          2
4     2        1 Married                          2
5     2        0 Married                          2
6     3        0 Single                           0
7     3        0 Single                           0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. I forgot to mention that NO household has more than two single or married adults living in it. How would the code then change?

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually having trouble creating the total_adults variable. Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: If you want to use `dplyr` to find out the total number of adults in a household you can use this code: `individual_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(total_adults = sum(if_adult))`

Comment: Then you can use MrFlick's dplyr code or you can use the base R code I suggested. Both should give you the same result.

Comment: I'm getting an error for both codes. I want to create an entirely new column that shows total adults for each household id first:

   
 individual_data$`adults in household` <- individual_data %>% 
    group_by(individual_data$hh_id) %>% mutate(individual_data$`adults in 
    household` = sum(individual_data$if_adult))    


But I keep getting this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument.

Comment: when you use the pipeline operator, `%>%`, you don't need to type the name of the dataset again. all you have to do is this: `individual_data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(adults_in_household = sum(if_adult))`

Comment: also note that in your dataset the column name is `\`if_adult (>18 yrs old)\`` and I have assumed that the column name is `if_adult`. You might want to change that.

Comment: Yeah I did exactly what you did but im still getting the same error. 
and you're right about the if_adult assumption. I first created an empty column for adults_in_household like this:
    individual_data["adults_in_household"] <- NA
Then I used your code to populate it

Comment: what's the class of `if_adult` field? you don't need to add that empty field `adults_in_household`, the mutate function will that for you.

Comment: I have added reproducible and tested code at the end of the answer I gave. Hope this helps.